# I have a problem in editing the ACF repeater index storing

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Here is my main problems for now:
I have a custom (something like portal) to manage purchase orders all built with ACF
I have a custom post type named 'purchase-order'
and another custom post type named 'item'
inside the purchase order I have a repeater named 'items'
inside the row I have the fields:
item:post-object [getting the data from the post type 'item']-return post-object
price:number
quantity:number
notes:textarea
vendor_notes:textarea
delivery_date:data
pallets:repeater [pallet_number:number || pallet_quantity:number]

now, I'm printing an automated comment when any of these fields changes [price, quantity, notes, vendor_notes, delivery_date]
and it's working fine
But, if I delete a row, the indexes of the rows is being resseted and it's printing comments for all the rows after the deleted row
and it's logical since the index of all of them has been changed
I want to prevent this
now, I'm looping over the repeater rows by the row index and it's the main problem
I want to loop over the rows by the subfield named 'item'
for example
instead of dealing with the subfield price of the first row like this: items_0_price
I want to get it like this: items_$item_price
in my mind it's something like adding another attribute to the row called 'item' or to loop over all the rows and check the changes by the subfield 'item' value

the second problem is, I want to print a comment when a new row is added or when a row is deleted
the 3rd problem is: I want to make the field 'item' uneditable after the first change of it
for example:
day 1: I created the purchase order and I added 5 items then I saved it
these 5 items, their rows, the item field must be disabled
day 2: I decided to add more 3 items, the field 'item' must be editable for the first add then when I saved they became disabled
also I have some other challenges I want to discuss

I tried to use chatgpt and copilot but none of them gave me a solution